# Game task C# in Conditionals

Tags: c#, conditional-statements

Three friends came up with a game for having fun in the break between the classes. One of them says a three-digit number and the others use it to form a mathematical expressions by using operators for sum and multiplication between the digits of that number.

The winner is the first one who founds the biggest number that is a result of the above mentioned rules.

Write a program 'game', which prints out that biggest number.

Input
Read from the standard input

The first line of the input will be positive three-digit number N.
Output
Print on the standard output

The result should be the calculated biggest number.

Example:

```
185
41
111
3
```

I can only get 7/10 answers. I cannot cover every single scenario here. I wrote against my judgement over 10 ifs and still cannot cover every case. Please help here.

```
enter code here

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        //Console.WriteLine(N);
        int X = N % 10;
        int Y = ((N / 10) % 10);
        int Z = ((N / 100) % 10);
        int sum = 0;
        //Console.WriteLine(X);
        //Console.WriteLine(Y);
        //Console.WriteLine(Z);
        if (X == 0 && Y == 0 && Z == 0)
        {
            sum = 0;
          //  Console.WriteLine(sum);

            if (X == 0 && Y == 0)
            {
                sum = Z;
                // Console.WriteLine(sum);
            }
            if (Y == 0 && Z == 0)
            {
                sum = X;
                // Console.WriteLine(sum);
            }
            if (Z == 0 && X == 0)
            {
                sum = Y;
                // Console.WriteLine(sum);
            }
            if (X == 1 && Y == 1)
            {
                sum = Z + X + Y;
                // Console.WriteLine(sum);
            }
            if (Y == 1 && Z == 1)
            {
                sum = Z + X + Y;
                // Console.WriteLine(sum);
            }
            if (Z == 1 && X == 1)
            {
                sum = Z + X + Y;
                // Console.WriteLine(sum);
            }
            if (X == 1 && Y == 0)
            {
                sum = X + Z;
            }
            if (X == 0 && Y == 1)
            {
                sum = Z + Y;

            }
            if (X == 1 && Z == 0)
            {
                sum = X + Y;
            }
            if (X == 0 && Z == 1)
            {
                sum = Z + Y;
            }
            if (Y == 0 && Z == 1)
            {
                sum = Z + X;
            }
            if (Y == 1 && Z == 0)
            {
                sum = Y + X;
            }


        }
        else if (X == 1 && Y == 1 && Z == 1)
        {
            sum = X + Y + Z;
        }
        else if (X == 1 || X == 0)
        {
            sum = (Y * Z) + X;
        }
        else if (Y == 1 || Y == 0)
        {
            sum = (X * Z) + Y;
        }
        else if (Z == 1 || Z == 0)
        {
            sum = (X * Y) + Z;
        }
        else
        {
            sum = X * Y * Z;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sum);

    }


}
```

Comment: @D-Shih thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!
I used my Java code and converted it to C#.

```
enter code here

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        //Console.WriteLine(N);
        int a = N % 10;
        int b = ((N / 10) % 10);
        int c = ((N / 100) % 10);
        int sum = 0;
        //Console.WriteLine(X);
        //Console.WriteLine(Y);
        //Console.WriteLine(Z);
        if ((a > 1) && (b > 1) && (c > 1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a * b * c);
        }
        if ((a == 0) && ((b <= 1) || (c <= 1)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(b + c);
        }
        if ((a == 0) && ((b > 1) && (c > 1)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(b * c);
        }
        if ((a == 1) && (b > 1) && (c > 1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a + b * c);
        }
        if ((a == 1) && ((b <= 1) || (c <= 1)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a + b + c);
        }
        if ((a > 1) && ((b <= 1) && (c <= 1)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a + b + c);
        }
        if ((a > 1) && (b == 1) && (c > 1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a * b * c);
        }
        if ((a > 1) && (b == 0) && (c > 1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a + b + c);
        }
        if ((a > 1) && (b > 1) && (c <= 1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a * b + c);
        }


    }
}
```